# getchar in while loop reading multiple lines stdin

Tags: tree, getchar

I have used this code for reading in a set of lines of input *in one go* to finally store them in a ***double dimensional character array***.  If i encounter a '\n', i increment the row index of the doubledim char array..

I then have to analyze the resulting double dim char array line by line and perform associated functions.

The problem is that the code shows:

> 'TIME LIMIT EXCEEDED'

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <malloc.h>

    struct Trees
    {
    int num;
    struct Trees *left;
    struct Trees *right;
     };

     typedef struct Trees t;
     t *root = NULL;


     int main(void) 
     {
    void insert(int,t **);
    void print_pre(t *);
    void print_post(t *);

    char *q;
    char a[2] = " ";
    char all[100];
    char line[30][100];
    int yy;
    int nn;
    int i,l,j,k,s;
    i=0;j=0;k=0;s=0;

    while ((all[i]=getchar())!=EOF)        //where i start getting input data
    {                                      // notice the  single dim char array 'all'
                                           //for storing everything
        if(all[i] != '\n')
          line[j][k++]=all[i++];       //the double dim array 'line'
        else
        {
            i++;
            j++;
            k=0;
        }
    }
    l=j;
    j=0;
    while(l>=0)
    {
    if (strncmp(line[j],"insert",6) == 0)
    {
        q = strtok(line[j],a);
        while(q != NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(q,"insert") != 0)
            {
                yy = atoi(q);
                break;
            }
        }
        insert(yy,&root);
    }
    else if (strncmp(line[j],"print_pre",9) == 0)
    {
        print_pre(root);
    }
    else
    {
        print_post(root);
    }
    return 0;
    j++;
    l--;
    }
    }

    void insert(int d, t **n)
       {
      if (*n == NULL)
    {
        (*n)=(t*)malloc(sizeof(t));
        (*n)->left = NULL;
        (*n)->right = NULL;
        (*n)->num = d;
    }
    else if((*n)->num == d)
    {
        insert(d,&((*n)->left));
    }
    else if((*n)->num > d)
    {
        insert(d,&((*n)->left));
    }
    else
    insert(d,&((*n)->right));
}

void print_pre(t *n)
{
    if(n!= NULL)
    {   printf("ffs");
        printf("%d",n->num);
        print_pre(n->left);
        print_pre(n->right);
    }
}

void print_post(t *n)
{  
    if(n!= NULL)
    {
        print_post(n->left);
        print_post(n->right);
        printf("%d",n->num);

    }
}
```

Comment: are you doing this on Windows? have you use a debugger to see which line went wrong? Have you tried any debugging at all?

Comment: Yes using windows. Sad to say but i dont know how to use any debugger.  I dont think any infinite loop is happening

Comment: Tag the language. You will get more attention.

Comment: Thanks guys got it. should have used the fgets-sscanf combo pair!